# VWAP calulation on investing.com is different than what the formula gives

Tags: stocks, investing

I have been trying to code a VWAP implementation in my Python code. I used the formula that is suggested on many sites:
VWAP = (Typical Price x Interval Volume) / Cumulative Volume

However the values of VWAP as coming on investing.com are different than what I get by using this formula. is there a different way to calculate VWAP ?

The Python code that I wrote on similar lines is below :

```
''' typicalPrice = (open + high + low)/3
    VP = volume * typicalPrice
    totalVolume = np.cumsum(volume)
    totalVP = np.cumsum(VP)
    VWAP = totalVP/totalVolume'''
```

I am using TA-LIB python library in my code and it doesn't have a VWAP implementation.

Are there any other Python libraries which have VWAP implementation ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a thing about Python nor have I ever looked at the VWAP indicator.

What I can tell you are trying to replicate an indicator that involves moving averages or some sort of cumulative sum  or difference, the respective indicator values will not be the same  unless the data values and the data period used is same.

Comment: Hi Bob, I am downloading the data in real time from investing.com itself hence I am suspecting that mine and their formula differs in calculation. Actually in the beginning of the time period our numbers look very close but they keep on diverging during the day. I suspect they do some kind of divergence management in the calculation.